How to identify a specific resource in AnyLogic during simulation?
I am simulating a port environment and I want to colect some information in a table about my resources, all created in resource Pool, to use it in a code without exporting data. I am already doing part of it but I couldnt find a way to collect the “Resource ID” to identify the specific resource that I am taking information from, considering that I have more than one Resource per type.
Here is a screenshot of my ResourcePool setup:
enter image description here
The part of the code located on “On Release” that I am using to write inside the table is:
        unit.data_mant = date();
        insertInto(maintenance_data)
        .columns(maintenance_data.machine_type, maintenance_data.when_out, maintenance_data.times_out)
        .values(unit.type, unit.data_mant, unit.qtd_mant)
        .execute();

How can I rewrite this code to add the “ID” information in the colum “machine_id” that I plan to create?

You don't. If you want to use the info within the model itself (i.e. not for outputs), do not use a dbase. This is extremely inefficient and unnecessary complicated.
You already have all the info and data by just accessing the resource units directly.
Loop across them anytime during the model run and do with their info whatever you want (plot in a chart, store in a dataset...)
Example pseudo code:
for (MyResourceType currResource : myResPool.agents()) {
    // do what you want
}


Thank you. I understood your point, but after re-evaluating my problem, there is a need to export the data for further analysis in my research. So, I need to keep the database. To continue searching for a solution, I think I wasn't very clear about the location of my codes:

The ResourcePool is in Main, containing the code to insert resource information into a database (as detailed in the question).
The resource itself was generated as a new agent, with all its parameters.
Inside this resource agent is also located the code that needs to use the information previously described.


best always open new, clean, revised, concise questions, SOF does not work like a forum but is a Q&A place. Some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
